# Why iOS13 changes the font-family inside NSAttributedString for paragraphs <p>

Tags: swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

My application uses NSAttributedString to display text to the user. Most of this text is inside the paragraph HTML tags (`<p>`). When it's inside the tags, the font family is changed to some Times style.
It happend in the new version iOS 13, before we did not hve this problem.

On this image you can see normal font and the modified font when it is in the

tags: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG2F8.jpg

We don't know where to start looking for the solution.

```swift
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
let strDesc: String = "\(explanation)\n"
let newStringDesc = strDesc.replacingOccurrences(of: "</ul>", with: "</ul><br>")

let modifiedString = "<style>body{font-family: '\(font.fontName)'; font-size:\(font.pointSize)px;}</style>\(strDesc)"
guard let data = modifiedString.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }

let attrString = try NSMutableAttributedString(
    data: data,
    options: [
              NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,

NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,
                ],
    documentAttributes: nil
)
attrString.addCustomParagraphSettings(font: font)
attrString.setCustomParagraphFontColor()

let mainAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()

mainAttributedText.append(attrString)
mainAttributedText.append(tmpTakenText)
descriptionTextView.attributedText = mainAttributedText
```

I expect to see standard iOS font.

Comment: And what print `font` or `font.fontName`?

Comment: fontName = ".SFUI-Regular"

Comment: font-family:  shouldn't byt font.familyName instead?

Comment: Yes, now it works! Thanks @Larme

Comment: I'd say that previously, it wasn't finding the font because it should be familyName (the param name is saying so), and by default put some SF Font or Helvetica Neue giving you the impression it was working. Now why shouldn't it return if not found San Francisco font is strange.

Comment: I found one more thing quite strange - when I removed this like, it was still using this wrong font. Apparently, it's the default font for the paragraphs or something like that.

Comment: This solution seems to work, but it only works when the required font is the regular one, because it is the one returded by default from the font family. `font.fontName` is supposed to specify exactly which font from the family is required, i.e. thin, bold, heavy...

Answer (score 3):

@Larme found a bug in the code. The value of the `font-family` CSS property should be `font.familyName` and not `font.fontName`.

Comment: I confirm that I run in the same problem, the CSS does not accept fontName and fall backs to default font, with familyName it works